# Neo4j data consistency issue

Tags: java, neo4j

I got empty result error when accessing neo4j database with the following setup.

- Neo4j runs in docker.
- Uploader process runs continuously with 0.5 second sleep between each
  upload
- Reader process runs continuously as well

Reader:

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://db_address:7687", AuthTokens.basic("user", "password"));
while (true) { 
    try (Session session = driver.session(AccessMode.READ)) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            session.run("Match (n:Number) where n.value=$value return ID(n)", parameters("value", i)).single().get(0).asInt();
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Uploader:

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://db_address:7687", AuthTokens.basic("user", "password"));
while (true) {
    try (Session session = driver.session(AccessMode.WRITE)) {
        try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
            tx.run("MATCH (n) DELETE n");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                tx.run("CREATE (n:Number {value: $value}) return ID(n)", parameters("value", i)).single().get(0).asInt();
            }
            tx.success();
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

After few cycles I get error in the reader process:
Cannot retrieve a single record, because this result is empty.

At start the database contains the requested data.
Based on the description of "write transaction" and the code above the empty result seems strange.

Did I miss something with the transaction handling with neo4j?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `tx.success()` to commit the transaction.

PS: not sure why the database is cleared on every upload run

Comment: I tried the proposed solution, but I have the same error.
I want to refresh the full content of the database, therefore the clear at every update.

Comment: This sort of test is quite flaky if it depends on thread sleeps and dropping databases- could you not clear the database and check first if nodes are even written?

Comment: I agree about the flakiness of this concurrency test, but it provides the same error what I got with my applications and of course it can write the database. But as I mentioned in my question my "reader application" sometimes sees an empty database, which should be impossible because the "uploader application" clears and fills the database in one transaction.